# What does contextual where clause `ID == Element.ID` mean?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been reading up on the source code of this Swift package [SwiftUIPager](https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager/blob/master/Sources/SwiftUIPager/Pager.swift) and found this extension on line 186:

```
extension Pager where ID == Element.ID, Element : Identifiable {

    /// Initializes a new Pager.
    ///
    /// - Parameter data: Array of items to populate the content
    /// - Parameter content: Factory method to build new pages
    public init(page: Binding<Int>, data: [Element], @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Element) -> PageView) {
        self._pageIndex = page
        self.data = data
        self.id = \Element.id
        self.content = content
    }

}
```

The original init (line 144) asked for an `id` explicitly, whereas this one does not since Element is of the type Identifiable.

The one part of the code I don't understand is why `ID == Element.ID` is necessary and what it means exactly? Removing it causes a compile-time error:
`Key path value type 'Element.ID' cannot be converted to contextual type 'ID'`

Swift's documentation only talks about `A == B`, which I understand, but what is `A == B.A` supposed to mean?

Comment: read up on [generic constraints](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID192). Basically, it means that a generic type `ID` of `Pager` is the same as the `ID` type of `Element` (also a generic type constrained to `Identifiable`, which itself has a generic type `ID`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pager` type is defined with generic types `Element`, `ID`, and `PageView`

```
struct Pager<Element, ID, PageView>: View
```

with constrains on each:

```
where PageView: View, Element: Equatable, ID: Hashable {
```

The extension applies to a case where the generic type `ID` of `Pager` is the same as the generic type `ID` of `Element`, and where `Element` conforms to `Identifable`:

```
extension Pager where ID == Element.ID, Element : Identifiable
```

Why should `Element` have a generic type `ID`? Because `Element` is constrained to `Identifiable`, which is [defined](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) with an associated type `ID`:

```
protocol Identifable {
   associatedtype ID
   ...
}
```

So, in other words, the extension applies only when `Pager` has an `Element` that conforms to `Identifiable` with the same type of `ID` as its own `ID`

Comment: Thank you, the part that I missed was that Identifiable protocol had `associatedtype ID`, this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you for your succinct explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this code it looks like Element is an array. Element.Id is looking at the ID of that specific element in the array. So it is checking to see if the element ID is equal to the ID. If you didn't have element.id it wouldn't know which element in the array it should look at.